# Data from separate function being merged in excel

Tags: php, excel, function

Im working on 2 json data which I need to transfer the data to separate excel files. What I did is, I made 2 function so that I can choose what file to be downloaded. The problem is when I tried to call both, the data is merged on a single excel. What I expect is it will be downloaded separately.

I tried adding sleep after the first function but didn't work, still the same output. I tried also using die after both function but only the first one is working.

Hope you help me.

**SAMPLE CODE**

*function.php*

```
<?php

function bjpk(){
    $json = 'api link...';
    $arr = json_decode(file_get_contents($json), true);
    $name = $arr['code'];
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$name.xls\"");
    header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel;");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: 0");
    $out = fopen("php://output", 'w');

    $data = array();

    foreach ($arr['data'] as $key => $value) {

    $data['date'] = substr($value['opentime'], 0, -9);
    $data['num'] = substr($value['expect'], 4);
    $codes = explode(',', $value['opencode']);

    foreach ($codes as $key => $code) {
        $data[$key] = $code;
    }

        fputcsv($out, $data,"\t");
    }


    fclose($out);
}

function cqssc(){
    $json = 'api link..';
    $arr = json_decode(file_get_contents($json), true);
    $name = $arr['code'];
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$name.xls\"");
    header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel;");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: 0");
    $out = fopen("php://output", 'w');

    $data = array();

    foreach ($arr['data'] as $key => $value) {

    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd', substr($value['expect'], 0, -3));

    $data['date'] = $date->format('Y-m-d');
    $data['num'] = substr($value['expect'], 8);
    $codes = explode(',', $value['opencode']);

    foreach ($codes as $key => $code) {
        $data[$key] = $code;
    }

        fputcsv($out, $data,"\t");
    }


    fclose($out);

}
```

*index.php*

```
<?php

require_once ('function.php');

bjpk();

cqssc();
```

Comment: You can't download 2 files at the same time (unless you zip and download them that way).  When you output the files you dump them into the output buffer.  You only have one output buffer so the second one is just appended on to the first (probably after some header warnings as you cant call header after output is started)

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix I see. thanks for that.

Comment: Sure...  Easy mistake to make.  You can use ZipArchive in PHP to zip them, though.  http://php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php